# Asynchronous Task calls to synchronous and asynchronous functions

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function that requires the preparation of a string for a SQL statement. It works both ways as listed below but I am brand new to async methods and the documentation is a bit overwhelming. My naive instinct is that it would be better if the returned string comes from an async method in case anything is shared but then another part of me thinks that nothing is really shared. Is there anyone that can explain the difference to me between the 3 calls (including one with await) and any potential trouble with the code below?

*for context: This is an Azure Function running on a CosmosDB trigger intended to flatten and write the file to an Azure SQL Server. The expected number of updates in Cosmos is about 200 per second*

```
public static async Task Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> input, TraceWriter log)
{
    //parameters set based on input Document
    string queryText1a = await firstSqlPrep(parameters);
    string queryText1b = firstSqlPrep(parameters);
    string queryText2 = secondSqlPrep(paremeters);

    //run the SQL statement after one of these

}

public static async Task<string> firstSqlPrep(parameters)
{
     //prepare query text
     return "some string";
}
public static string secondSqlPrep(Document inputDocument)
{
     //prepare query text
     return "some string";
}
```

Comment: *in case anything is shared but then another part of me thinks that nothing is really shared* - what's that?

Comment: @Nikhil Vartak Well I worry that it will get the wrong string back as a query to send because another thread from this function called the same method.

Comment: @kyarbles. because you don't perform any asynchronous action inside your `firstSqlPrep` or `secondSqlPrep`  functions, your code will run synchronously. There is no problem with it. Async call are useful if you call the database itself, call an external service or start a long running task in the background. I would suggest you not to worry too much about that. Just make the call (run the sql statement) asynchronous and it will be good

Comment: Thanks. Helps me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do some kind of I/O inside `SqlPrep` method, there's no sense in returning `Task<string>` from it. Both of your methods will run synchronously, but actually `firstSqlPrep` will induce some overhead related to creation and `await`-ing the `Task`.

Use `secondSqlPrep` in your code. Keep using `async`-`await` for the database call itself.

Comment: Makes sense and helps decide when to use async. Thanks!